# Git branch and merge : modifications from 2 branches with no conflict?

Tags: git, merge

I'm puzzled by the git behaviour and i would like to have some explanations.
Let me explain, i have 2 branches :

- *master*
- *my_feature_branch.*

---

The workflow :

- day 0 : i create *my_feature_branch* from *master*
- day +1 : from *my_feature_branch* : i do a change in the file "feature.java"
- day + 2 : from *master* i do a change in the file "feature.java"
- day + 3 : from *my_feature_branch* i merge *master* into *my_feature_branch*

---

Result : No conflict. my_feature_branch do not retrieve the changes from master in "feature.java". 
Git considers that "feature.java" from my_feature_branch is all correct.

Consequences : The fix did in master is not reported in my_feature_branch.

Comment: Is there a remote repository involved? What are the exact commands you used to perform the merge?

Comment: Note that simply modifying the same file in two branches and then merging isn't guaranteed to generate a merge conflict in Git. In fact, very often it doesn't. If you've made modifications to different parts of the file, e.g. to your constructor in one branch, and adding a new method in another branch, Git will often merge just fine.

Comment: Yes, there is a remote repo involved.  he problem here is  there is no merge at all.

Answer (score 1):

in most cases, Git will figure out how to integrate new changes.

However, there's a handful of situations where you might have to step in and tell Git what to do. Most notably, this is when changing the same file. Even in this case, Git will most likely be able to figure it out on its own. But if two people changed the same lines in that same file, or if one person decided to delete it while the other person decided to modify it, Git simply cannot know what is correct. Git will then mark the file as having a conflict - which you'll have to solve before you can continue your work.

Comment: No merge, no conflict. Git simply dump out the modification from master.

Comment: You get your changes from master because your branch is merged with master or vice verse . without merge git can not dump modifcation from master. this link can help to understand http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging